# Passing Arguments to a Closure(?)

Tags: r, closures

I'm trying to create an enclosing function which will:

- process some data,
- `cat()` results of that data,
- request user input (ie, via `readline()` ) based on the results of that `cat()`,
- then return a function where one of the argument defaults of the returned function is the value inputted by `readline()`.

Additionally, I'd like the remaining default values of the arguments of the returned function to be user-interpretable.  That is, I don't want the defaults to be variable names of variables hidden in the parent environment (this stipulation precludes simple argument passing).  Specifically, I'd like `arg()` to return actual evaluated numbers, etc.

I've cooked up this solution below, but it feels clunky and awkward. Is there a more elegant way of approaching this?

```
top <- function(year=1990, n.times=NULL){

if(is.null(n.times)){
    ###in the real function, data would be processed here
    ###results would be returned via cat and
    ###the user is prompted return values that reflect a decision
    ###made from the processed data
    n.times <- as.numeric(readline("how many times?"))
}


out <- function(year, n.times){
    ###in the real function, this is where most of the work would happen
    rep(year, n.times)
}

###this entire section below is clunky.
if( !identical( names(formals()), names(formals(out)) ) ){
     stop("internal error: mismatching formals")

}

pass.formals <- setdiff( names(formals()), "n.times")

formals(out)[pass.formals] <- formals()[pass.formals]
formals(out)$n.times <- n.times
out

}

x <- top()
x
```

Comment: I do not have an answer, but would strongly suggest you pick a different name for your function. `outer` is a matrix-creation function in base-R. The usual way to process arguments is with the `match.arg()` function.

Comment: I don't it's going to hurt anything in this toy example, but I fixed it nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks generally OK to me; there's only a few things I'd do differently.

Is there any reason that the parameters of `top()` and `out()` seem to correspond in some
way? ie, do you need the `identical` check? Not sure, so I took it out. This seems to do what you
want, and is slightly shorter:

```
top <- function(year=1990, n.times=NULL){
    if (is.null(n.times)) {
        n.times <- as.numeric(readline("how many times?"))
    }

    out <- function(year, n.times) {
        rep(year, n.times)
    }

    out.formals = formals(out)
    out.formals['n.times'] = n.times
    formals(out) = out.formals

    out
}
```

**edit:** And if you want to use super R magic, you can write

```
top <- function(year=1990, n.times=NULL){
    if (is.null(n.times)) {
        n.times <- as.numeric(readline("how many times?"))
    }

    `formals<-`(
        function() {
            rep(year, n.times)
        },
        value=list(year=alist(x=)$x, n.times=n.times)
    )
}
```

**edit**: You could also use something like DWin suggested (though I couldn't
get it to work with `substitute`):

```
    out = function(year, n.times) {
        rep(year, n.times)
    }
    `formals<-`(out, v=`[[<-`(formals(out), 'n.times', n.times))
```

Or using `bquote`:

```
    eval(bquote(
        function(year, n.times=.(n.times)) {
            rep(year, n.times)
        }
    )[-4L])
```

You have so many options.

Comment: Could you do something even more compact like ` `formals<-`(out, substitute(formals(out), list(n.times=n.times))) `? Sorry, I couldn't get the backquotes to display correctly in the comment.

Comment: @DWin I wish, but I couldn't get it to work with `substitute`. But that same idea would work with `[[<-`.